# How to assign a suitable science category to keywords, using DBPedia and SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have some keywords like `emotion perception ability`, `students’ motivation`, `self-efficacy`. The goal is to map these keywords to a corresponding category(-ies) of psychology. In this case I know apriori that the answer is [Educational psychology](http://dbpedia.org/page/Educational_psychology), however I want to get the same answer using DBPedia ontologies.

Using the following query I am able to extract different branches of psychology and corresponding abstracts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?abstract
WHERE {
?concept rdfs:label "Branches of psychology"@en .
?concept ^dct:subject ?subject .
?subject dbo:abstract ?abstract .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Now I want to add some OPTIONAL clause that would compare my keywords (using OR) with terms from the abstract (`dbo:abstract`). Is it possible to do this using SPARQL? Or should I use SPARQL just to obtain the abstracts and then to make all further text processing using e.g. Java or Python?

Also, the ideas of some other approaches that might be useful to reach the goal are highly appreciated.

Comment: Usually SPARQL is not designed for extended NLP processing. What means "compare"? Look for abstracts that contains all, some,... words? Some triple stores support extended text search features - often by using a Lucene index in the backend. Otherwise you could try to use FILTER + REGEX, but that's indeed not that fast .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve data as text using sparql, but deciding if a text match a query should be done with text data analysis technics, or [text mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining)

This is a whole science, but fortunately **lots of libraries** for many languages (including Java and Python) exist in order to implement related algorithms. [Here is a list of software on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_mining_software). NLTK is well-known for the job, and have a Python binding.

In your case, i think of many ways, but i'm far from an expert, so my idea can be wrong:

Create a corpus of abstracts of each desired categories (educational psychology,…), and, for a given abstract A, compare A to each abstract of each abstract of each category C. The result of the comparison will give for each category a score/likelihood that A belongs to C. (cf [fuzzy sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set))

The comparison could be implemented with [vector space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model), that works on vocabulary similarities.

[Named Entities Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) could help to detect names of authors, technics or tools related to particular category.

Main idea is the following: once you defined what is the particular trait of each category, by using its vocabulary, authors, references or whatever, you can decide, for any abstract, a score of membership to all categories.

So, the real question to ask is *which scoring function should i use ?*.
The answer depends heavily of the data, and the results you want. When you say an abstract is about educational psychology, you have to know why. And then implement it as a scoring function.

As a side node, i add that neural networks, by training on the corpus, could, maybe, bypass the scoring, by automatic learning. I don't know enough in that field to say more.